# Is there a name for right angle braces / brackets that have enlarged holes for adjustments?

Tags: brackets

I like building furniture, and at times need to use right angle brackets. The problem is that when I'm screwing them in, right at the end they'll shift the tiniest bit which throws off everything. Infuriating when I've spent hours cutting and sanding everything right.

I was digging around my unused hardware drawer and came across this:

[image]

It is 1" x 1/2", which design-wise would be perfect, though need a bunch in different sizes. Is there a name for this type of brace or bracket?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's called an **[angle shrinkage](http://www.screwfix.com/search?search=shrinkage%20angle)**. Or at least, the particular type which allows expansion in two directions is.

Products may also be called **[angle stretcher plates](http://media.jetpress.com/vajrbvzljx/Angle-Stretcher-Plates-2-Holes-2-Slots.jpg?width=580&height=580)**.